# Pulling data out from a text file in PHP

Tags: php

I am very new to PHP and am trying to create a basic form. This form has a drop-down list whereby the product is displayed. What I would like for it to do is to display the price, and the city that this product is from.

I have a text file which acts as the data source, and is formatted in this way:

```
product | price | city
```

Code:

```
<?php

   $file = 'Product1.txt';
   $handle = @fopen($file, 'r');
   if ($handle) {
       while (!feof($handle)) {
           $line = fgets($handle, 4096);
           $item = explode('|', $line);
           echo '<option value="' . $item[0] . '">' . $item[0]. ' '.$item[1]. ' '.$item[2].'</option>' . "\n";
       }
       fclose($handle);      
   }
   ?>
```

Overall, when I populate my dropdown list, it works fine, and I've extended the page with the hopes of getting more. However, when I try to echo `$item[1]` or `$item[2]` at the end of the page, I get nothing.

Can someone show me what I am missing? I've tried looking for tutorials on this matter but to no avail. Thank you.

```
<?php
echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
echo $name;
echo "<br>";
echo $_POST['D1'];
echo "<br>";
echo $quantity;
?>
```

Comment: put $item = array(); at the top after $handle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting anything because $item not in scope

put $itemData = array(); at the top after $handle

```
   $file = 'Product1.txt';
   $handle = @fopen($file, 'r');
   $itemData = array();
   if ($handle) {
       while (!feof($handle)) {
           $itemData[] = explode('|', $line);
           $line = fgets($handle, 4096);
           $item = explode('|', $line);
           echo '<option value="' . $item[0] . '">' . $item[0]. ' '.$item[1]. ' '.$item[2].'</option>' . "\n";
       }
       fclose($handle);      
   }
```

its should work

Comment: Thanks @Saqueib. It still isn't working though. How should I invoke item[1] and item[2]?


Do I need to edit this as well? This is the configuration of the drop-down list. 

<option selected="selected" value=<?php echo $item[0]?>>--Please Choose a Product--</option>

Comment: dont edit dropdown, you will need $itemData[0][0] to access product

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = explode(" | ", file_get_contents("data.txt"));
```